# YA horror/fantasy short stories: greenhouse, body-swapping, and a hurricane

Tags: young-adult, story-identification

I'm looking for fantasy or horror anthologies I read as a child/young teenager (1992-1995):

Two stories that might be from the same one:

A teenager has taken a summer job working for a relative who grows tomatoes in a large greenhouse.  It seems that as you walk towards the door, it gets further and further away.  She always keeps a radio on to keep their bearings.  Eventually she gets trapped in and can't run to the door no matter what, and has to be rescued somehow.  There's a fire at that time, and the relatives decide to spend the insurance money on a swimming pool - which the protagonist says she will NEVER swim in!

The other is a child who goes to an adventure playground with his family and meets a very friendly and charming girl wearing a t-shirt with a smile on it.  They make friends and play.  At the end of the day the boy's parents call him and he turns around to see himself getting into the car with his family!  He looks down and sees he is wearing the smile t-shirt.  He tries to phone home through the operator but they won't accept the call from their child as "their" child is right there in the house!  The boy has no choice but to wait at the park for someone else to swap with.

There's an episode of The Twilight Zone with the same plot, set at a bus station.

Lastly, the world is ravaged by a very strong hurricane that goes round and round the earth.  The characters know they won't survive the next wave.  It was definitely in an anthology and not "The Wind From Nowhere" by JG Ballard.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd make thew last one a separate question, if it's not in the same anthology.

Answer (score 3):

Could the last one be [*The Fifteenth Wind of March*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74520)? Google attributes this story to Frederick Bland, but I could have sworn I ran across it in a Fred Hoyle collection.